# stringToHex and hexToString C# anf Android Java

Tags: c#, java, android, encryption, hex

here are the whole story:
(1) I have string "123";
(2) Encrypt to "????g*Ox*??D#?\v" using EncryptFromBase64;
(3) Converted to hex string using ConvertStringToHex

Here is the C# code.

```
       public string ConvertStringToHex(string asciiString)
    {
        string hex = "";
        foreach (char c in asciiString)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(c);
            // Convert the decimal value to a hexadecimal value in string form. 
            hex += String.Format("{0:X2}", value);
        }
        return hex;
    }

    public string ConvertHexToString(string HexValue)
    {
        string StrValue = "";
        while (HexValue.Length > 0)
        {
            StrValue += System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(HexValue.Substring(0, 2), 16)).ToString();
            HexValue = HexValue.Substring(2, HexValue.Length - 2);
        }
        return StrValue;
    }
    public string Encrypt(byte[] encryptedData)
    {
        byte[] newClearData = rijndaelEncryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(newClearData);
    }

    public string EncryptFromBase64(string encryptedBase64)
    {
        if (encryptedBase64.Length < 1) return "";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptedBase64);
        return Encrypt(bytes);
    }
```

(4)The hex string is then transported to Android request command to C# web service and converted back to string. using convertHexToString
(5) Decryt using decryptAsBase64. There is padding exception.

Here is the android code.

```
    public String decryptAsBase64(String clearData) {
    if(clearData.length() < 1) return "";
    byte[] encryptedData = clearData.getBytes();        
    byte[] decryptedData = decryptAsBase64(encryptedData);
    String str = Base64.encodeBytes(decryptedData);
    str = str.replace("+", "%2B");
    return str;
}
public byte[] decryptAsBase64(byte[] clearData) {
    byte[] decryptedData =decrypt(clearData);
    try {
        return Base64.decode(decryptedData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decryptedData;
}
   public byte[] decrypt(byte[] clearData) {

    byte[] decryptedData;
    try {
        decryptedData = aesCipher_Decoder.doFinal(clearData);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Illegal block size", e);
        return null;
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bad padding", e);
        return null;
    }
    return decryptedData;
}
```

public String convertHexToString(String hex){

```
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      //49204c6f7665204a617661 split into two characters 49, 20, 4c...
      for( int i=0; i<hex.length()-1; i+=2 ){

          //grab the hex in pairs
          String output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
          //convert hex to decimal
          int decimal = Integer.parseInt(output, 16);
          //convert the decimal to character
          sb.append((char)decimal);
      }
      return sb.toString();
    }
```

The string converted back "????g*Ox*??D#?" is incorrect.

Anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but using a `StringBuilder` would be better in c# than `+=` a normal string variable.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but your C# code can be written like this: `return asciiString.Select(x => String.Format("{0:X}, Convert.ToInt32(x));`

Comment: As I see, the converted back is "????g*Ox*??D#?" which is missing 2 chars '\' and 'v'. Does it repeat with other strings? Or result in completedly different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved. The error is in the encryption and decryption codes. The following code

```
 public string Encrypt(byte[] encryptedData)
 {
    byte[] newClearData = rijndaelEncryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(newClearData);
  }
```

should be

```
     public string Encrypt(byte[] encryptedData)
    {
        byte[] newClearData = rijndaelEncryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
     //   return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(newClearData);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(newClearData);
    }
```

In the android decryption code. The code

```
  public String decryptAsBase64(String clearData) {
  if(clearData.length() < 1) return "";
  byte[] encryptedData = clearData.getBytes();        
  byte[] decryptedData = decryptAsBase64(encryptedData);
  String str = Base64.encodeBytes(decryptedData);
  str = str.replace("+", "%2B");
  return str;
}
```

should be

```
 public String decryptAsBase64(String clearData) {
    if(clearData.length() < 1) return "";
    byte[] encryptedData = null;
    try {
        encryptedData = Base64.decode(clearData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] decryptedData = decrypt(encryptedData);
    String str = null;
    try {
        str = new String(decryptedData, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
 }
```

Comment: It involves AES encryption and it is not plain text. On android, getBytes() will return byte array with default UTF-8 charset. It meets my need. What is your solution? Please list code if you have better one.

Answer (score 2):

You're grabbing the hex characters in pairs in your `convertHexToString()` method, but your `{0:X}` format string doesn't necessarily output 2 hex digits per character. If you want to make sure each character is represented by 2 hex digits, then use this format string instead:

```
{0:X2}
```

Comment: I had this format before. The problem is "\V" not converted correctly.

Comment: You should post the code that you're actually using. What you have won't even compile (wrong capitalization for .NET methods, etc). Also, if you're really using `hex.substring(i, (i + 2))` then that's wrong. The second argument should be a count, so just `2`. Assuming that that's not a custom extension method that you created it, being all lowercase and everything.

Comment: The first portion is C# code and the second portion is Android code. I changed back forth to fix the problem. All codes posted can be compiled.